# Is it possible to have a sub-select in a HQL dateAdd function?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, hql

I am having some trouble with a HQL dateAdd function in Hibernate 3.

In the following code I want to get all matters which have a lastTimeDate greater then the maximum deadline plus 3 months.

```
<cfoutput>
        <cfsavecontent variable="hSql">
            from matter as m
            where m.lastTimeDate < dateAdd(month, 3, (select max(d.cutOffDate) from deadline as d))
        </cfsavecontent>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfset var awMatters = ormExecuteQuery(hSql) />
```

However when I execute the query I receive the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s).
```

Am I missing something? There are definitly 3 arguments in my dateAdd function.

I am using Coldfusion 9 (ORM) along with a MSSql 2005 server.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the alias name proper? Would you mind trying this?

```
 <cfsavecontent variable="hSql">
            from matter as m
            where m.lastTimeDate < dateAdd(month, 3, (select max(cutOffDate) from deadline))
        </cfsavecontent>
```

Answer (score 0):

do the `select max(d.cutOffDate) from deadline` first

then `ormExecuteQuery("from matter where lastTimeDate < ?", [dateAdd('m', 3, cutOffDate)])`